# Delimiting transactions in a text file with bash

Tags: regex, bash, file, grep

I've got a text file with the following pattern:

```
06:52:25 -> TRANSACTION START
06:52:26 - line1
06:52:27 - line2
06:52:29 -> TRANSACTION END*
06:53:24 -> TRANSACTION START
06:53:25 - line3
06:53:40 - line4
06:53:52 -> TRANSACTION END
```

I would like to separate every occurrence of starting transactions and ends into separate files

Comment: I think this should belongs to http://superuser.com/ if you need complete code, if you need only `regex` then it's fine here

Comment: @Tushar it'as totally fine here.

Comment: @AvinashRaj `I would like to seperate every occurence of starting transactions and ends INTO SEPARATE FILES` bothers me

Comment: what are the output names ( of the split files )

Comment: output file names could be trans_1.txt, trans_2.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
awk '/TRANSACTION START/{file="trans_"cont++".txt"}{print $0 >> file}' inputfile
```

**Explanation:**

`/TRANSACTION START/{file="trans_"cont++".txt"}`: When the `START` pattern is matched the target file name is updated.

`{print $0 >> file}`: Print every line in the current file with `>>` to avoid overwrite.

Comment: And if the OP has 10k transaction, the last line will be `print $0 > "FILE10000"` ?

Comment: Yeah thanks, but what I really need is the content between every  'code' TRANSACTION START and TRANSACTION END, included, thanks

Comment: Yeah Thomas, in my script I intend to use these files as temporary files, so they will be deleted later !

Comment: If the OP want a bash/regex combo, I seriously doubt (but I might be wrong) that he just have two files to compute

Comment: Thanks @klashxx, can I have a detailed explanation please ?